# How to print foreign text on a plot using R

Tags: r

I am trying to print some foreign character on an image using `text()`. The foreign characters are from a TrueType font. The text gets completely deformed on my plot.

Here is a code snippet:

```
library(imager)

load.example("parrots") %>% plot
text(x=400, y=100, "parrot", family = "Arial", cex=5)
text(x=400, y=400, "सुगा", family = "Kantipur", cex=5)
```

Comment: Try using LaTeX expressions: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html

Comment: I cannot find a way to get it work with LaTex either: 

load.example("parrots") %>% plot(main=TeX("सुगा"))